# Animal Crossing New Horizons - Can I take villager's furniture away, which I made for them?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

At about beginning of game, I had made some furniture for 3 new Villagers. Now they're all in my island.

What I see is those furniture still put outside of their house, can I take it back?
(I haven't tried)

If I can, and I do, will it reduce/low-down their favorability and make them leave my island?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take them and it won't affect how they like you. It's considered just like any other item placed outside.

I suspect the game makes you do this for two reasons : learn how to craft and have some "island points" thanks to furniture placed outside.

Comment: I'm like screaming to them "I spend all my iron nugget and my time, you waste those furniture  outside!? GIVE IT BACK TO ME !!!"        Ha Ha :~D